# credential id not work with jenkins ansible plugin adhoc class

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, ansible, jenkins-operator

I am using [step([$class: 'AnsibleAdHocCommandBuilder']): Invoke Ansible Ad-Hoc Command](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ansible/#stepclass-ansibleadhoccommandbuilder-invoke-ansible-ad-hoc-command) to invoke adhoc command in my pipeline, but somehow, it gives error when use `credentialsId` to pass the private key variable.

```
step([
  $class: 'AnsibleAdHocCommandBuilder',
  ansibleName: 'Run cvWatchBuilder',
  inventory: [$class: 'InventoryPath', path: "myhost,"],
  hostPattern: "all",
  module: 'shell',
  disableHostKeyChecking: true,
  command: 'ls',
  forks: 1,
  credentialsId: 'ssh-private-key'
  ]);
```

When this step run, it gives error for private key.

```
Running on k8s-6930a022-327d-44a2-9065-cae0fde58c14-s8pbx-70c8d in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/k8s-e2e
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run shell)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] step
Executing sh script inside container ansible of pod k8s-6930a022-327d-44a2-9065-cae0fde58c14-s8pbx-70c8d
Executing command: "ansible" "all" "-i" "myhost," "-m" "shell" "-a" "ls" "-f" "1" "--private-key" "/tmp/ssh11730288813016418676.key" "-u" "devops" 
exit
myhost | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added 'myhost,172.17.203.19' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\n\n\n__________                __                                     __                 _________ .____    .___\n\\______   \\_____    ____ |  | ____ ________   ____  ____   _____/  |_  ___________  \\_   ___ \\|    |   |   |\n |    |  _/\\__  \\ _/ ___\\|  |/ /  |  \\____ \\_/ ___\\/ __ \\ /    \\   __\\/ __ \\_  __ \\ /    \\  \\/|    |   |   |\n |    |   \\ / __ \\\\  \\___|    <|  |  /  |_> >  \\__\\  ___/|   |  \\  | \\  ___/|  | \\/ \\     \\___|    |___|   |\n |______  /(____  /\\___  >__|_ \\____/|   __/ \\___  >___  >___|  /__|  \\___  >__|     \\______  /_______ \\___|\n        \\/      \\/     \\/     \\/     |__|        \\/    \\/     \\/          \\/                \\/        \\/\n\n\n\nno such identity: /tmp/ssh11730288813016418676.key: No such file or directory\r\ndevops@myhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
FATAL: command execution failed
hudson.AbortException: Ansible Ad-Hoc command execution failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.ansible.AnsibleAdHocCommandBuilder.perform(AnsibleAdHocCommandBuilder.java:224)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:100)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:70)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

But when use same key with `sh` function, it works.

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'ssh-private-key', keyFileVariable: 'keyfile')]) {
                    sh("ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible all -i myhost, -m shell -a ls --private-key $keyFile -u devops")
                }
```

This works and print output as below.

```
Running on k8s-8f822fb4-b0bf-4c8d-9df2-9fa3da5e4a55-v9j9n-kdbtg in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/k8s-e2e
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run shell)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $keyfile
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [keyfile]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible all -i myhost, -m shell -a ls --private-key **** -u devops
myhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
```

**EDIT**

I debug little more, then sees that, it complain about `/tmp/ssh11730288813016418676.key: No such file or directory`, then I was thinking to see where this file is :)

We are using Jenkins-operator on kubernetes cluster to run the jenkins instance. What it will do is, it create 2 container in pod. One for `jnlp` to connect to jenkins master, and second to use for the execution.

My full pipeline is as below.

```
$ cat cicd/pipelines/k8s.jenkins
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def label = "k8s-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"
def home = "/home/jenkins"
def workspace = "${home}/workspace/build-jenkins-operator"
def workdir = "${workspace}/src/github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-operator/"

podTemplate(label: label,
        containers: [
            containerTemplate(name: 'ansible', image: 'my registry/ansible', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
//          containerTemplate(name: 'ansible', image: 'python', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
        ],
        ) {
    node(label) {
        stage('Run shell') {
            container('ansible') {
//              withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'ssh-private-key', keyFileVariable: 'keyfile')]) {
//                  sh("ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False ansible all -i myhost, -m shell -a ls --private-key $keyFile -u devops")
//              }
//              sh 'pip install ansible'
                step([
                    $class: 'AnsibleAdHocCommandBuilder',
                    ansibleName: 'Run command',
                    inventory: [$class: 'InventoryPath', path: "myhost,"],
//                  inventory: [$class: 'InventoryPath', path: "localhost,"],
                    hostPattern: "all",
//                  module: 'shell',
                    module: 'pause',
                    disableHostKeyChecking: true,
                    command: 'minutes=5',
//                  command: 'ls',
                    forks: 1,
                    additionalParameters: '-vvv',
                    credentialsId: 'ssh-private-key'
                ]);
                sleep time: 60
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I check the jenkins console log, it shows that which pod it created and what it runs under which container.

```
Running on k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn in /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/k8s-e2e
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Run shell)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] step
Executing sh script inside container ansible of pod k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn
Executing command: "ansible" "all" "-i" "myhost," "-m" "pause" "-a" "minutes=5" "-f" "1" "--private-key" "/tmp/ssh6159272872640967836.key" "-u" "devops" "-vvv" 
exit
ansible 2.10.11
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.8 (default, Mar 31 2021, 12:38:11) [GCC 8.3.0]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
Parsed myhost, inventory source with host_list plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.
META: ran handlers
Pausing for 300 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
myhost | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "delta": 300,
    "echo": true,
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2021-12-15 19:45:35.186293",
    "stderr": "",
    "stdout": "Paused for 5.0 minutes",
    "stop": "2021-12-15 19:50:35.186787",
    "user_input": ""
}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 1 min 0 sec
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

from above message, it created `k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn` pod in our kubernetes cluster. When I did `describe` on that pod, I see there are 2 containers running in this pod.

```
# kubectl describe pod k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn -n jenkins
Name:         k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn
Namespace:    jenkins
Priority:     0
...
...
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.221.84
IPs:
  IP:  192.168.221.84
Containers:
  ansible:
    Container ID:  containerd://400d9360a9b3a1415335d6e57148a58d2e64576649323e203a9b66a0de2b048a
    Image:         myrepo/ansible
    Image ID:      myrepo/ansible@sha256:6b797d6f80c7ec8c209bec8bde363b84c910a68b4b608c9db6a0411acff3b515
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      cat
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 15 Dec 2021 19:45:30 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    ...
    ...
    Mounts:
      /home/jenkins/agent from workspace-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-mrww8 (ro)
  jnlp:
    Container ID:   containerd://f592bf372bf8fde5baca8a28918b275125fea9b66c9d6ea422172adb29c688ac
    Image:          jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4-jdk11
    Image ID:       docker.io/jenkins/inbound-agent@sha256:2ee9fb7405f135e15ea3c5efaa605b7c19bc0a93a306deec7a0826a489c1a364
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 15 Dec 2021 19:45:31 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  256Mi
    Environment:
      JENKINS_SECRET:                                      0e0f75a0d4e42f0b6c0964f12a1bd1d331d75b0578d8b0e1fd2a7fd9d1175b9d
      JENKINS_TUNNEL:                                      jenkins-operator-slave-jenkins-instance.jenkins.svc.cluster.local:50000
      JENKINS_AGENT_NAME:                                  k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn
      JENKINS_NAME:                                        k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn
      JENKINS_AGENT_WORKDIR:                               /home/jenkins/agent
      ...
      ...
    Mounts:
      /home/jenkins/agent from workspace-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-mrww8 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  workspace-volume:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-mrww8:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  3m13s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned jenkins/k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn to myworker
  Normal  Pulled     3m13s  kubelet            Container image "stepladder-docker-local.artifacts.rackspace.net/ansiblelint:latest" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    3m13s  kubelet            Created container ansible
  Normal  Started    3m13s  kubelet            Started container ansible
  Normal  Pulled     3m13s  kubelet            Container image "jenkins/inbound-agent:4.3-4-jdk11" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    3m13s  kubelet            Created container jnlp
  Normal  Started    3m12s  kubelet            Started container jnlp
```

In the console log it has log line as `Executing sh script inside container ansible of pod k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn` means `ansible` command will run in `ansible` container of pod.

When I check the `/tmp` directory in `ansible` pod, I didn't see any files in that.

```
# kubectl exec -i -t k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn -c ansible -n jenkins -- ls -al /tmp/
total 8
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4096 Dec 15 19:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Dec 15 19:45 ..
```

While as per the ansible command, there should be file `/tmp/ssh11730288813016418676.key` exists in the `/tmp` folder. Then I check the `jnlp` container.

```
# kubectl exec -i -t k8s-d83c8383-beca-4cfb-ac61-5b8df98d76e7-t4s7w-chmhn -c jnlp -n jenkins -- ls -al /tmp/
total 20
drwxrwxrwt 1 root    root    4096 Dec 15 19:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4096 Dec 15 19:45 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 4096 Dec 15 19:45 hsperfdata_jenkins
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 Mar 31  2020 hsperfdata_root
-r-------- 1 jenkins jenkins 3243 Dec 15 19:45 ssh11730288813016418676.key
```

I can see the `sshXXXX.key` file is created in `jnlp` container.

When ansible command runs on `ansible` container, it is not able to find the `sshXXXXX.key` file on that container, and it gives error that `no such file or directory`.